# laravel pivot table get wrong records

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pivot-table, laravel-5.4

this is "evalution" table

```
-id
-title
-slug
```

this is "member" table

```
-id
-name
-surname
```

this is "evalution_member" pivot table

```
-evalution_id
-member_id
```

evalution table has 3 records as below

```
id | title | slug
1 | a | a
2 | b | b
3 | c | c
```

member table has 10 records as below

```
id | name | surname
1 | xx1 | xx1
2 | xx2 | xx2
3 | xx3 | xx3
4 | xx4 | xx4
5 | xx5 | xx5
6 | xx6 | xx6
7 | xx7 | xx7
8 | xx8 | xx8
9 | xx9 | xx9
10 | xx10 | xx10
```

evalution_member table has 10 record as below

```
evalution_id |member_id
1 | 1
1 | 2
1 | 3
3 | 4
3 | 5
3 | 6
3 | 7
3 | 8
3 | 9
3 | 10
```

this is my Evalution model

```
public function members()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Member');
}
```

this is my Member model

```
public function evalutions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Evalution');
}
```

And this is my code :

> $evalution = Evalution::find($id)->with('members')->first();

Return member list from this code but coming wrong records . Right records must start on 4th item and end on last item but return list contains first 3 records.

if i change Evalution model as below :

```
public function members()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Http\Models\Member', 'evalution_member', 'evalution_id', 'member_id');
}
```

return list contain only 1 record that is last record on the evalution_member table.

why ?

what is the problem in there ?

Comment: Are you sure you are sending the right $id

Comment: i will check it again but i sure the right id

Answer (score 0):

Add pivot table name to methods like this.

```
public function members()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Member', 'evalution_member');
}
```

Comment: i change the controller code like this : $evalution = Evalution::with('members')->find($id);

it works ...